# How to deactivate scaled image preliminary smoothing?

Tags: wpf

I've got a `Grid` with some scale transform applied; the `Grid` contains an image:

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="5.7" ScaleY="3.7"/>
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
    <Image Source="rw.bmp" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

The image is 2 by 1 pixels, one pixel red and one white:

[image: original image]

I expect to get such a rendered image (stretched):

[image: stretched expected image]

but I actually get this one (again stretched):

[image: stretched actual image]

You can see that the actual rendered image is somehow kind of smoothed before stretch, instead of being smoothed after stretch.
Is there a way to get the image as in the expected example?

---

Edit: tried different values of `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode`. The closest to what I need is "NearestNeighbor", which gives the following:

[image: not quite]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive, but could you somehow use [`RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.bitmapscalingmode.aspx) with this?

Comment: Tried each of them. The closest to what I need is `NearestNeighbor`, but it's still not quite the needed image. Thank you for the idea anyway!